# How to map a list of entities into a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, map, entity

```
x = RandomChoice[CountryData[]]
```

Here I have defined x to be a random country.

```
citynames = Dynamic[p = CityData[{Large, Last[x]}]]
```

Then I defined the large cities with p.

```
t = Dynamic[InputForm[p]]
```

This converts all of them into entities as such:

```
Entity["City", {"Baghdad", "Baghdad", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlMawsil", "Nineveh", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlBasrah", "Basra", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Irbil", "Arbil", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Kirkuk", "AtTamim", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Sulaymaniyah", "Sulaymaniyah", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AnNajaf", "AnNajaf", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Karbala", "Karbala", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AnNasiriyah", "DhiQar", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlAmarah", "Maysan", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AdDiwaniyah", "AlQadisiyah", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlKut", "Wasit", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlHillah", "Babil", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"ArRamadi", "AlAnbar", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlFallujah", "AlAnbar", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AbuGhraib", "Baghdad", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"TallAfar", "Nineveh", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Samarra", "SalahAdDin", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AsSamawah", "AlMuthanna", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Baqubah", "Diyala", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"Dahuk", "Dahuk", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlKufah", "AnNajaf", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AzZubayr", "Basra", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"SattAlArab", "Basra", "Iraq"}], 
Entity["City", {"AlFaw", "Basra", "Iraq"}]}]
```

Now I'd like to map all of these entities into

```
CityData[*entity here*,"Coordinates"] and CityData[*entity here*, "Name"]
```

Map doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to format it properly.

Comment: I am confused by your use of `Dynamic`and `InputForm` here. However, you should be able to use `CityData[#, "Coordinates"]& /@ yourListofEntities`.

Comment: The Dynamic is for something else that I didn't include.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting "Missing[Not Available]"

Comment: That's not what I get. Here is a small example: `CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ {Entity["City", {"Baghdad", "Baghdad", "Iraq"}], Entity["City", {"AlMawsil", "Nineveh", "Iraq"}]}`. This returns a list of coordinates, one for each city.

Comment: You would want to clean up your code, remove the parts that do not matter (e.g. the Dynamic etc) and show exactly what code you are running that gives you trouble. For instance, your current code does not produce the list you show, so it is hard to try and fix it because we are probably not working with the actual code you have.

Answer (score 1):

First, a minor point. I would use [`RandomEntity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomEntity) instead of [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice) *([`RandomEntity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomEntity) will be much faster for entity types with a large number of entities, e.g., "Star")*

```
entity = RandomEntity["Country"]
```

> Entity["Country", "IvoryCoast"]

Then, you can get the cities with:

```
cities = CityData[{Large, CanonicalName @ entity}]
```

> {Entity["City", {"Abidjan", "Lagunes", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Bouake", "ValleeDuBandama", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Daloa", "HautSassandra", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"SanPedro", "BasSassandra", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Yamoussoukro", "Lacs", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Korhogo", "Savanes", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Man", "DixHuitMontagnes", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Divo", "SudBandama", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Gagnoa", "Fromager", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Abengourou", "MoyenComoe", "IvoryCoast"}], 
>    Entity["City", {"Anyama", "Lagunes", "IvoryCoast"}]}

Finally, to obtain the coordinates and names you can use EntityValue:

```
EntityValue[cities, {"Coordinates", "Name"}]
```

> {{{5.33, -4.03}, "Abidjan"}, {{7.69, -5.03}, "Bouake"}, {{6.89, -6.45}, 
>     "Daloa"}, {{4.77, -6.64}, "San\[Hyphen]Pedro"}, {{6.82, -5.28}, 
>     "Yamoussoukro"}, {{9.45, -5.65}, "Korhogo"}, {{7.4, -7.55}, 
>     "Man"}, {{5.85, -5.37}, "Divo"}, {{6.15, -5.88}, "Gagnoa"}, {{6.73, -3.49}, 
>     "Abengourou"}, {{5.5, -4.05}, "Anyama"}}

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! Question: I wanted to make a tooltip to highlight the name coordinates and names of cities. How would I do it. I have this so far: `Manipulate[Button["Random", entity = RandomEntity["Country"]], 
 Dynamic[DynamicGeoGraphics[
   Tooltip[GeoMarker[cities], EntityValue[cities, "Name"]]]]]`